# How to install certificates on docker images without dockerfile?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-container-registry

My middleware team has a pipeline on azure devops that pulls a bunch of images from docker hub regularly and republish it on our private repository.

I would like to alter the pipeline to not only copy/paste the images, but also install our CA Root certificates.

The release pipeline consist of 3 steps:

1. a bunch of `docker pull RemoteRepository.com/image:latest`
2. `docker tag RemoteRepository.com/image:latest InternalACR.io/image:latest`
3. `docker push InternalACR.io/image:latest`

Because there's no `dockerfile` involved, I was wondering if it's possible to keep it that way.

What is the recommended approach here?

Comment: 1) The simplest method is to use a Dockerfile. 2) You could use **docker exec** and then **docker commit**. Your root CA would need to be accessible to Azure DevOps.

Comment: And also `docker commit` is basically never a best practice; you'd have to repeat that exact same step the exact same way every time a new build was produced.  You can write a pretty trivial Dockerfile `FROM remoterepository.com/image:latest` (or a build-specific tag) that `COPY` the certificate files to a known location, and then set up your CI system to build and push the images.

Comment: I actually use almost 100 different base images... Is there any way which I don't have to create 100s different dockerfiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and recommended method is to use a Dockerfile. It is a simple task to take an existing container and then modify it to create a new container.

Example:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/#{baseImage}# AS base

COPY RootCA-1.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
COPY RootCA-SubCA-1.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/

RUN update-ca-certificates
```

You can also run an existing container, modify it while the container is running. You can then commit the changes to a new container.

Example commands:

```
docker exec ...
docker cp ...
docker commit ...
```

Refer to this answer for an additional technique with Azure Pipeline:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70088802/8016720

Answer (score 0):

Well... I actually didn't do it without the dockerfile, but I created a template file and looped over on a pipeline. Like this: [Azure Pipeline to build and push docker images in batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70086863/azure-pipeline-to-build-and-push-docker-images-in-batch)

Comment: This should be added to your question as this is not an answer to your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley pls post your comment as answer and ill accept it and remove mine... If you could please link the other question for a complete reference, id be grateful