# Azure Pipeline to build and push docker images in batch?

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have to pull a bunch of docker images, install some root CA certs on them and push them to a private repo.

The logic I came up with is:

1. Create a template docker file (Dockerfile.Template)
2. On a pipeline, declare all the base images to be pulled
3. Run one by one on the dockerfile replacing the image name
4. Push one by one

The template dockerfile I came up with is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/#{baseImage}# AS base

COPY RootCA-1.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
COPY RootCA-SubCA-1.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/

RUN update-ca-certificates
```

The azure pipeline is:

```
trigger:
- master

parameters:
- name: 'images'
  type: object
  default: 
  - sdk:6.0
  - sdk:5.0
  - sdk:3.1
  - sdk:2.1

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- ${{ each baseImage in parameters.images }}:

  - bash: |
     echo "current image is $(BASEIMAGE)"

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
      Contents: 'Dockerfile.Template'
      TargetFolder: 'Dockerfile'
  - task: replacetokens@4
    inputs:
      targetFiles: 'Dockerfile'
      encoding: 'auto'
      tokenPattern: 'default'
      writeBOM: true
      actionOnMissing: 'warn'
      keepToken: false
      actionOnNoFiles: 'continue'
      enableTransforms: false
      useLegacyPattern: false
      enableTelemetry: true

  - task: Docker@2
    inputs:
      containerRegistry: 'MyPrivateRegistry'
      repository: 'dotnet/$(baseImage)'
      command: 'buildAndPush'
      Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
```

My current problem is that the replace token activity is not replacing the `#{baseImage}#` for the docker activity.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing like this:

```
steps:
- ${{ each value in parameters.images }}:
  - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=baseImage]${{ value }}"
  - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=tag]${{ replace(replace(replace(value,'sdk:',''),'runtime:',''),'aspnet:','') }}"
  - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=baseImageName]${{ replace(replace(value,replace(replace(replace(value,'sdk:',''),'runtime:',''),'aspnet:',''),''),':','') }}"
  - bash: |
     echo "current image is $(baseImageName) and tag is $(tag)"
  
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: 'DockerfileTemplate'
      Contents: 'Dockerfile'
      TargetFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
      OverWrite: true

  - task: replacetokens@4
    inputs:
      targetFiles: 'Dockerfile'
      encoding: 'auto'
      tokenPattern: 'default'
      writeBOM: true
      actionOnMissing: 'warn'
      keepToken: false
      actionOnNoFiles: 'continue'
      enableTransforms: false
      useLegacyPattern: false
      enableTelemetry: true

  - task: Docker@2
    inputs:
      containerRegistry: 'MyPrivateRegistry'
      repository: 'dotnet/$(baseImageName)'
      command: 'buildAndPush'
      Dockerfile: 'Dockerfile'
      tags: '$(tag)'
    continueOnError: true
```

basically I moved the template dockerfile to a subfolder and renamed to just Dockerfile. Then I broke the `baseImage` into `baseImageName` and `tag`... and voila!